# Can we call delegate in an extension of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am not able to find any way to call the delegate in the below code and without delegate the **textFieldDidBeginEditing** method cant be called

```
import UIKit

class ModifiedTextField: UITextField { }

extension UITextField: UITextFieldDelegate{

func fieldEmptyError(value: Bool){

    let textFieldVal = "\(self.placeholder!)"

    if (value){
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        pulsate()
        textFieldOrigVal(string: textFieldVal, borderColor: UIColor.red)
    }else {

        textFieldOrigVal(string: textFieldVal, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)
        layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    }
}


public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.fieldEmptyError(value: false)
}


}
```

Comment: change your extension to `extension ModifiedTextField: UITextFieldDelegate`.

Comment: if i change my extension type to ModifiedTextField, I am getting error here           
    textField.fieldEmptyError(value: false)

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you update your code in the question?

Answer (score 4):

First you need need to replace your extension as

```
extension ModifiedTextField : UITextFieldDelegate{}
```

But you said that you get error doing this

You get error because fieldEmptyError method is available with ModifiedTextField not UITextField and you are calling method as textField.fieldEmptyError(value: false)

So you need to call method directly inside your extension

```
extension ModifiedTextField : UITextFieldDelegate{
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    fieldEmptyError(value: false)

}
}
```

And do not forget to set delegate
You can do it by storyboard or programmatically

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    delegate = self
}
```

So finally you entire code looks something like this

```
import UIKit
class ModifiedTextField: UITextField {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    delegate = self
}
 }
 extension ModifiedTextField : UITextFieldDelegate{
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    fieldEmptyError(value: false)

}
func fieldEmptyError(value: Bool){

    let textFieldVal = "\(self.placeholder!)"

    if (value){
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        pulsate()
        textFieldOrigVal(string: textFieldVal, borderColor: UIColor.red)
    }else {

        textFieldOrigVal(string: textFieldVal, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)
        layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I hope it helps you.

```
class ModifiedTextField { 
   viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       yourTextField.delegate = self
   }
}

extension ModifiedTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {

    public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          // Your code, what happend
    }
}
```